# PL/SQL trigger to insert values to another table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to create a trigger that inserts values to a temporary table, but I also want it to delete those values from the actual table I wanted to modify, to explain myself better:

I have created this table

```
create table R2(a int, b date);
```

And a temporary table that's basically the same as R2

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE R2TEMP
 AS SELECT * FROM R2;
```

If I do:

```
INSERT INTO R2 VALUES (1,'09/05/1995');
```

I want this trigger to insert those values in R2TEMP, instead of inserting them in R2 (I used a DELETE FROM R2 but I want to know how I can avoid it)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER BLOCK_INSERT2
BEFORE INSERT ON R2
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN


INSERT INTO R2TEMP(A,B)
SELECT * FROM R2;

DELETE FROM R2;
END;
```

I want to know how could I insert those values in another table, different than the one that caused the trigger, I hope I explained myself, and thanks for your time

Comment: Create a table named R2REAL. Make R2 a view on R2REAL instead of a table. Create an INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger on R2 (the view). Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the `instead of` trigger (documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96524/c18trigs.htm#10901)).

It is very easily coded:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER BLOCK_INSERT2
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON R2
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO R2TEMP(A,B)
        SELECT A, B FROM R2;
END;
```

I would advise you to list all the columns explicitly, instead of using `select *`.